# Obtener string de código qr

Tags: android

quería saber si es posible hacer una app utilizando alguna api de lector de qr, para leer los qr y guardarme el string que contiene para luego utilizarlo en consultas a la base de datos. Gracias!

Comment: Si, lo más común es usar Xing : https://github.com/zxing/zxing al capturar los datos puedes crear una operación para insertar en una BD mySQL

Comment: Es posible que muestres lo que has intentado?

Comment: Juan, por favor [edit] tu pregunta con el código que estés usando para este objetivo y los errores que puedas tener.

Comment: @Mauricio por ahora no he hecho nada aún, quería saber para así comenzar a desarrollar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sí, esta librería es una de las más utilizadas https://github.com/zxing/zxing
y esta respuesta adjunta ejemplos y documentacion https://stackoverflow.com/a/16082601/4959545

Comment: Maguz, no es recomendable contestar a preguntas que se van a cerrar, siendo las de opinion personal muy claras.